# Notice: Undefined index PHP

Tags: php, variables, global

I'm trying to build a registration/login system from this video tutorial series:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S6vDgLwJ7n8

I'm early in on this and if I don't get the answer I'm looking for will either 1. Give up or 2. Restart everything.
Anyway, here's the error it's giving me:

```
Notice: Undefined index: CONFIG in C:\xampp\htdocs\php_login\classes\config.php 
on line 5
```

My code:

Config.php :

```
<?php
class Config {
public static function get($path = null) {
if($path) {
$config = $GLOBALS['CONFIG'];
$path = explode('/', $path);

foreach($path as $bit) {
if(isset($config[$bit])) {
$config = $config[$bit];
 }
}
}

return $config;
}
}
```

index.php:

```
<?php
require_once 'core/init.php';

echo Config::get('mysql/host'); //'127.0.0.1'
```

init.php:

```
$GLOBALS['config'] = array(
'mysql' => array(
'host' => '127.0.0.1',
'username' => 'root',
'password' => '',
'db' => 'login'
),
'remember' => array(
'cookie_name' => 'hash',
'cookie_expiry' => 604800
),
'session' => array(
'session_name' => 'user'
)
);

function autoload($class) {
require_once 'classes/' . $class . '.php';
}
spl_autoload_register('autoload');


#JUST PUTTING THIS SHIT HERE:
//spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
// require_once 'classes/' . $class . '.php';
//});
//Un comment next line!
//require_once 'functions/sanitize.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
$config = $GLOBALS['CONFIG'];
```

with

```
$config = $GLOBALS['config'];
```

on your 5th line.